# Python list of strings to 1 string separated by comma & quotes (, & ")

Tags: python, string, list, join, quotes

I have a list of strings:
`list_of_strings = ["A", "List", "Of", "Strings"]`

I want to convert it to one new string looking like:

`new_string="""  "A", "List", "Of", "Strings"  """`

(
I tried to use the `join` function, but i didn't manage to do it properly:
`','.join(list_of_strings)` )

Comment: I think there's an XY problem here. What are you trying to achieve by building this string?

Answer (score 4):

You need the double quotes on your string.

```
new_string = "  " + ", ".join(['"{}"'.format(x) for x in list_of_strings]) + "  "
```

Comment: Because it lacks of the spaces before and after the string? @timgeb

Comment: True. Will fix that. Thanks!